# Load JSON inside a multi-select list

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to load via ajax some json objects within a mcDropdown jQuery Plug-in, here is the example http://khine.3b1.org/countries.htm

the data i want to load is returned from the following queries:

/;countries?iana_root_zone=fr

this returns all the regions.

```
  [{"name": "fr#alsace", "value": "Alsace"}, {"name": "fr#aquitaine", "value": "Aquitaine"}, {"name": "fr#auvergne", "value": "Auvergne"}, {"name": "fr#basse-normandie", "value": "Basse-Normandie"}, {"name": "fr#bourgogne", "value": "Bourgogne"}, {"name": "fr#bretagne", "value": "Bretagne"}, {"name": "fr#centre", "value": "Centre"}, {"name": "fr#champagne-ardenne", "value": "Champagne-Ardenne"}, {"name": "fr#corse", "value": "Corse"}, {"name": "fr#franche-comte", "value": "Franche-Comté"}, {"name": "fr#haute-normandie", "value": "Haute-Normandie"}, {"name": "fr#ile-de-france", "value": "Île-de-France"}, {"name": "fr#languedoc-roussillon", "value": "Languedoc-Roussillon"}, {"name": "fr#limousin", "value": "Limousin"}, {"name": "fr#lorraine", "value": "Lorraine"}, {"name": "fr#midi-pyrenees", "value": "Midi-Pyrénées"}, {"name": "fr#nord-pas-de-calais", "value": "Nord-Pas-de-Calais"}, {"name": "fr#pays-de-la-loire", "value": "Pays de la Loire"}, {"name": "fr#picardie", "value": "Picardie"}, {"name": "fr#poitou-charentes", "value": "Poitou-Charentes"}, {"name": "fr#provence-alpes-cote-d-azur", "value": "Provence-Alpes-Côte-d'Azur"}, {"name": "fr#rhone-alpes", "value": "Rhône-Alpes"}]
```

/;countries?iana_root_zone=fr&region=alsace

this returns returns all the counties for region=alsace and iana_root_zone=fr:

```
  [{"name": "fr#alsace#bas-rhin", "value": "Bas-Rhin"}, {"name": "fr#alsace#haut-rhin", "value": "Haut-Rhin"}]
```

how would you change the example at http://khine.3b1.org/countries.htm so that it loads the JSON that is being returned.

many thanks for any advice